# conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value4

Tags: valgrind

valgrind shows such errors..

```
   7471== 7 errors in context 4 of 6:
    ==17471== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==17471==    at 0x36EA6718D0: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
    ==17471==    by 0x36EA64818F: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
    ==17471==    by 0x36EA64F189: printf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
    ==17471==    by 0x4008F3: main (main.c:84)
    ==17471==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
    ==17471==    at 0x4004E8: ??? (in /user/gur39229/extension/assign1/bin/exe)
    ==17471==
    ==17471==
    ==17471== 8 errors in context 5 of 6:
    ==17471== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==17471==    at 0x36EA647E2C: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
    ==17471==    by 0x36EA64F189: printf (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
    ==17471==    by 0x4008F3: main (main.c:84)
    ==17471==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
    ==17471==    at 0x4004E8: ??? (in /user/gur39229/extension/assign1/bin/exe)
    ==17471==
    ==17471==
    ==17471== 8 errors in context 6 of 6:
    ==17471== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==17471==    at 0x4A07FB7: strcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:442)
    ==17471==    by 0x4008CC: main (main.c:83)
    ==17471==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
    ==17471==    at 0x4004E8: ??? (in /user/gur39229/extension/assign1/bin/exe)
```

my code : pls check the code all the initializations and the use of the variables after initiation. at line no. 83 it says uninitialized..y ? i dont understand .. pls help.

```
    /*Declaration*/
 42         int i = 0;
 43         int a[4]={0};
 44         char cstr[80];
 45         memset(cstr,0,80);
 46         int largest = 0;


     if(largest == 3)
 82                 {
 83                         strcpy(cstr,str_concat(v[1],v[2]));
 84                         printf("\t%s%s\n\n",cstr,v[3]);
 85
 86                 }
```

though i have initialised every variable still its showing valgrind error what to do ?

Comment: How is v[] defined/initialized?